# Matrix elements of irreducible inequivalent unitary representations of group G form orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{C}(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I'm having a hard time understanding this (translated literally from lecture script):

"let $\rho_1,...,\rho_k $ be a list of irreducible inequivalent unitary representations of a finite group G. $\rho_{\alpha,ij}(g), \alpha = 1,...,k$ denote the Matrix entries of $\rho_{\alpha}(g)$ w.r.t. an orthonormal basis. The functions $\rho_{\alpha,ij}$ then form an orthogonal basis of the space of functions from G to the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}(G)$"

I'm under the impression that "matrix elements" are just the matrix representation of the transform $\rho(g)$ acting on a vector space V. How, then, are they supposed to be used to build some function that maps G into the complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each $\rho_\alpha(g)$ is an endomorphism, which in some (orthonormal) basis defines a matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$, and those coefficients are called $\rho_{\alpha,ij}(g)$. Then $\rho_{\alpha,ij}(g)\in \mathbb{C}$, so the function $g\mapsto \rho_{\alpha,ij}(g)$ is a function from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Ah I get a function for every entry ij. For some reason I thought the ij was referencing the whole of the matrix entries (every possible ij). That's a neat result. Thanks!